# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^4+2}-\sqrt[3]{n^4+4n^3-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n+4}}} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me calculate
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^4+2}-\sqrt[3]{n^4+4n^3-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n+4}}} $$

I don’t understand very well what needs to be done here with roots. I tried to multiply the entire expression by the value of the numerator and denominator and divide the entire expression by $n^\frac{4}{3}$, but the resulting expressions were very large and I still did not understand what to do with them...

I don't know what L'Hôpital's rule is. We can't use it yet. Please don't use it if you try to explain this to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To get help here, you need to explain what you've tried, so that answerers have a sense of your understanding and don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I don’t understand very well what needs to be done here with roots. I tried to multiply the entire expression by the value of the numerator and denominator and divide the entire expression by $n^\frac{4}{3}$, but the resulting expressions were very large and I still did not understand what to do with them

Comment: Let $a$ equal the first term in the numerator and $b$ be the second term.  Since $(a^3-b^3) = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ multiply top and bottom by the appropriate factor that will kill the radicals.   The compare the highest degree term in the numerator to the highest degree term in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n^4+2}-\sqrt[3]{n^4+4n^3-1}}{\sqrt[3]{n+4}}=\frac{n^{4/3}\, \sqrt[3]{1+\frac 2 {n^4} }-n^{4/3}\, \sqrt[3]{1+\left(\frac 4 n -\frac 1 {n^4}\right) }} {n^{1/3}\, \sqrt[3] {{1+\frac 4 {n} } }}$$ So, you face three times
$$\large\sqrt[3] {1+\epsilon }$$

Use the binomial expansion and simplify as much as you can.